# Game of Go Area 51 Proposal at 100% Commitment

Tags: discussion

[The Game of Go proposal on area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11942/game-of-go) has reached 100% commitment.

The discussions we had about the MTG site, which were somewhat diverted as academic, are now relevant.

I updated [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106230/is-a-mini-site-approach-a-solution-to-these-area-51-proposals) to reflect this current information.